# HTML5 gamepad API issues (on Mac)

Tags: html, gamepad-api

I'm curious if anyone out there has been able to connect to the gamepad API with either a wireless xbox360 controller or a bluetooth PS3 controller on a Mac.  As you can see below, I have both controllers connected and get nothing showing in the console.  Yes, I've hit the buttons to make sure to get the handshake.  I just wanted to make sure that I'm not missing something completely silly before going and purchasing a wired 360 controller.

[image: connected controllers]

Comment: Something silly must be going on because there's no reason a wireless controller can't work for you just fine. "Connect to the gamepad API"... What API might that be?

Comment: There's a new HTML5 [gamepad API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/gamepad/raw-file/default/gamepad.html) that Chrome has implemented since v21, if I can recall correctly.  If you look at the bottom of the screenshot, you'll see that I don't get any feedback on the **navigator.webkitGamepads** object. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a PS3 controller via bluetooth, on mac chrome, confirmed here: http://html5gamepad.com/

What OS version / chrome version are you on?

Comment: Just tested this out and it is working properly!  I'm not sure if Chrome has just been updated or if it is my incompetence; I will revisit my code to find out.  Thanks!

Comment: I am on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5 with google chrome version 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit). My PS3 controller is not detected here. However, it works on firefox. Is there any workaround to make it work on chrome?